# Swap file's default location

Tags: swap

I have just created a swap file and now I want to check the location on this swap file.

How can I check on which partition my swap file is residing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably several ways to do this, but the simplest ones are:

```
sh@uruk:~$ cat /proc/swaps 
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/nvme0n1p3          partition   2097148 456     -2
```

```
sh@uruk:~$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/nvme0n1p3          partition   2097148 456     -2
```

Comment: i just type this command but its not showing "/dev/** rather just say /swapfile

Comment: cd / && ls -l swapfile

Comment: So it's a swap file, not like on my machine a swap partition, it's named "swapfile", and it's in the root directory of your root filesystem. To see what partition it's on, use `df /`.